# Android okHttp - How to identify response is for which request?

Tags: android, okhttp

How can I identify response is for which request if I am creating multiple requests in okHttpClient?
Please don't tell me to implement listener inside enqueue method.

Any solution for this?

```
public class OkHttpJavaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback {

    Request request1;
    Request request2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ok_http_java);

        String url1 = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1";
        String url2 = "https://reqres.in/api/unknown/2";
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        request1 = new Request.Builder().url(url1).build();
        request2 = new Request.Builder().url(url2).build();

        client.newCall(request1).enqueue(this);
        client.newCall(request2).enqueue(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        Log.e("ABC", "DEF");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        Log.e("ABC", "DEF");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call.request().url should work